# Create "git format-patch" output from existing "diff" file

Tags: git, linux-kernel, patch, format-patch

The Linux kernel maintainers accept patches formatted using the `git format-patch` output but should you want to use something like `splitpatch` or `patchutils` to split out hunks from an existing patch, is there a what to reconstitute these into the email format you get from `git format-patch`?

I have taken a look at the formats and it seems the metadata at the start of the `git format-patch` format is simple text (email address etc, commit hash (from the local commit)) and is probably stripped out anyway by the maintainers, so you could probably write it manually, and include some random data for the commit hash?

Am I correct? I ask because sometimes maintainers want patches to be split up into series, and I can't see an easy way to do this without using `git reset` to reset the commit with the original changes, and then commit them separately (to get a patch series), which is a tedious procedure.

It would be much easier to just split up the existing "big" patch in my opinion.

I guess one workaround is to create a branch, apply the diffs and then use `git format-patch` to create the patches, but can we do this directly, without having to create branches and commits?

Comment: There’s three parts. One is the header and email. Then `---<newline>`. Then the second part is some sort of free-form space where you can write things. Finally the patch/diff part.

Comment: I think you are overestimating how difficult it would be to generate an appropriate commit history. This (rewriting a commit history to make it cleaner and more manageable) is a relatively common operation and you would be well served by becoming comfortable with the process.

Comment: You are probably looking for `git reset HEAD~1; git commit -s --interactive -c ORIG_HEAD`. This will keep the changes in the working directory and allow to commit by hunks. This is supported by Git for ages. (Note, the `-c ORIG_HEAD` is to preserve the existing commit message. Perhaps you want it for some changes, so, you need to save them first, i.e. `commit` and then continue with `git commit -s --interactive`.)

Comment: Very good, thanks for this one. I think this is likely the easiest way, also to use `git add -p` to selectively add the hunks you might want, then regenerate the patches with `git format-patch`.

Comment: But you will need the commit message in each patch anyway. `git commit --interactive ...` is combined option to automate as much as possible in this scenario,

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what a “format-patch” looks like:

```
From 5b34bc4e22816f7f19bd26c15a08fe4c749b72f8 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
Message-ID: <5b34bc4e22816f7f19bd26c15a08fe4c749b72f8.1709316230.git.me@example.com>
In-Reply-To: [cover letter message-id]
From: Me <me@example.com>
Date: Fri, 1 Mar 2024 18:14:35 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] =?UTF-8?q?gitcli:=20drop=20mention=20of=20=E2=80=9Cnon-da?=
 =?UTF-8?q?shed=20form=E2=80=9D?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
To: git@vger.kernel.org
Cc: someone <someone@example.com>

<commit message>
---
<free form part>
<diff/patch>
```

We’ll also assume that you have a *cover letter* (see the
`--cover-letter` option) which is a separate format-patch file without
any patch part (it tells you what changes with this series but it’s not
something that will be applied).

Now you may copy this file into three parts and manually edit the patch
on each one. Or maybe you extract the patch from this format and edit it
with one of the tools you mentioned and send it back in. So with the
latter approach you:

1. extract the patch into three patch files;
2. Remove everything below the `---` *or* everything after the free form
   part if you are using the free form part to write something
3. Copy that edited original three times
4. For each of the copies you need to change the `Message-ID` to
   something unique. I guess plenty of languages have utilities to parse
   email headers and to generate some globally unique string that can be
   identified as a message id
5. For each of them you need to change the subject:

   - Change `[PATCH]` to `[PATCH n/3]` where `n` is the patch number
     (1–3)
   - Change the subject to the commit message. Keep in mind to encode
     UTF-8 if you are using that, but I guess that is unlikely in this
     context.
6. Write the commit message for each
7. Use cat(1) to combine each format-patch copy with the new patch
8. Since we assume that you have a cover letter format-patch file you
   don’t need to worry about the `In-Reply-To` headers. For each new
   format-patch copy they will point to this cover letter. Assuming you
   are using a “flat” in-reply-to scheme where all patches point back to
   the cover letter.
9. The cover letter tells you what patches are in this series. Now the
   cover letter will say that there is one patch, which is wrong. That
   should be changed. It’s just a git-shortlog(1) output it seems.
10. Optional: check out the branch you are basing this in detached HEAD
    mode (`git checkout --detach main`) and try to apply your patches
    with git-am(1). This will make sure that your patches are okay.

Now assuming that all of these files are in something like `./patches`
directory you can use git-send-email(1) on that directory.

You should now apply these patches with git-am(1) for your own use (see
next paragraph). Maybe label this version with `git tag my-series/<branch-name>/v1`.

You send out this series. Now you get some feedback: patch 1 should be
split into two patches and patches 2–3 should be squashed. You also get
some feedback on typos in one of the commit messages and a formatting
mistake in patch 2.

Now you need to check out `git tag my-series/<branch-name>/v1` and
repeat the above process.

An alternative approach is to use tools like git-rebase(1) and
git-reset(1) to do all the changes you need to do with git(1). Then when
you use `git format-patch` you only need to review what you are sending
out and edit the cover letter file. But I would recommend doing as much
preparation as possible with git(1) as you can;[1] you can for example
write the cover letter beforehand and use `--description-file`[2] to
feed it to the command together with
`--cover-from-description=subject`.[3]

So if you are doing everything with git(1):

1. Prepare your changes
2. `trash patches` (or `rm -r patches` if you don’t have or don’t want
   to use a trash utility)

   - This is useful in case you have patches from previous runs that
     won’t get clobbered because the filenames are not the same. So you
     don’t send out more than you intend.
3. Use git-format-patch
4. Review what you are about to send out with `cat patches/* | less`
5. Send it out with git-send-email(1)

#### Discussion

I haven’t contributed to the Linux Kernel but projects which use mailing
lists can have pretty high standards when it comes to the commit
history. A few typos in the commit message could lead to a new version
of the series. One too many unrelated formatting changes could lead to a
new version. Not splitting or squashing things appropriately (like you
mention) is very likely to lead to a new version. It’s in my opinion
best to just get comfortable with history rewriting using git(1) if you
plan to contribute to a mailing list-based project.

#### Notes

1. Doing the “last minute” edits on the cover letter can get really
   tedious as you always spot little mistakes (in my experience). Better
   to be able to recreate everything from one command.
2. You need Git 2.43 for this
3. The first line of the file becomes the subject, the rest is put in
   the body. Like a commit.

Comment: I suggest you to read the question carefully.